# iCloud container missing for active App

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud

My App was released on the App Store a year ago, and used an XCode 5 compatible iCloud container that had the ID `TEAM_IDENTIFIER_PREFIX.com.company.name`

I'm doing an update to it and cannot upload it to the AppStore using XCode 7 because of error: `ITMS-90163, 'the bundle contains a key that is not including in the provisioning profile'`

The problem is that in the iOS Dev Center, my old iCloud container is not listed (even though it is used in a released App). There is a new iCloud container called `iCloud.com.company.name`, but using this breaks compatibility with the App currently on sale (i.e. all users lose their cloud documents).

I had assumed that iCloud containers cannot be deleted or in any way go missing after they are used in a released App. Has anyone seen this happen, or had to resolved a similar problem with updating an old App using the old iCloud container format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found that Apple has moved all old iCloud containers `TEAM_IDENTIFIER_PREFIX.com.company.name` to use the new naming format `iCloud.com.company.name`

I just used the new container in XCode 7 and everything worked correctly, and I could submit the App.

I'd been thrown off because (A) this does not seem to have been explicitly documented anywhere, and (B) there are some other answers on Stack Overflow that explicitly state that the two differently named iCloud containers are **not** the same, which does not appear to be true.

Comment: Not only is it not documented; the existing documentation still refers to the team identifier prefix. Still! (Late 2019.)